# Run Ajax from java script function in tpl file PRESTASHOP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-modules

Im working on a PrestaShop payment method and I have a tpl page with a button and a div which is hidden. On the button click, I want to execute an ajax function and show the div on success, but its not doing anything.

HTML Elements:

```
<input id="showVerifCode" type="button" value="Get Verification Code" style="background: #3e64ff; border-color: #3e64ff; color: #fff; padding: 11px 16px; cursor: pointer; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 2px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; margin-top: 16px; margin-bottom: 0px;">

  <div id="verifCode" style="display: none;">
    <p style="margin-top: 5px;"><small id="email-send-info" style="color: #6fdc6f;">Please check your mail for the verification code!</small></p>
    <P style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 16px;">Verification Code:</P>
    <input placeholder="E.g 1234567890" width="50px" name="verifCode" required type="text" style="margin-top: 1px; width: 100%; padding: 12px 20px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
  </div>
```

JavaScript Function:

```
{literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const targetDiv = document.getElementById("verifCode");
      const btn = document.getElementById("showVerifCode");
      btn.onclick = function () {
        
        $.ajax({
          url: {$link->getModuleLink('prestashopbeam', 'AjaxSendMail.php', array())},
          type: 'GET',
          data: 'ajax=true&clientgroups='+ 'test5858',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            if (targetDiv.style.display === "none") {
              targetDiv.style.display = "block";
            }
          }
        });

      };
    </script>
  {/literal}
```

PHP Ajax page (located in /modules/my_module/AjaxSendMail.php

```
<?php
return;
```

I only have this return there because I want to test out the ajax part first.

Sorry if this a very noob question but this is the first time I am using ajax, and I am no PHP or JavaScript master either.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I have tried using JQuery but the result is the same. I made sure the code runs when the button is pressed by only making it show the hidden div and it works, but not when I put the ajax code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    {literal}
    $( "#showVerifCode" ).click(

        function() {

          $.ajax({
            url: {$link->getModuleLink('prestashopbeam', 'AjaxSendMail.php', array())},
            type: 'GET',
                    data: 'ajax=true&clientgroups='+ 'teste5858',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
              $("#verifCode").show();
            }
          });
        }
    );

    {/literal}

  </script>
```

EDIT 2: The link was why this was giving problems. I have change to url to `url: '{/literal}{$link}{literal}',` but the request on my browser tools still gives a 404 not found despite the path looking alright to me.

[Image of Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbpKY.png)

EDIT 3: I fixed it. The issue was still with the url. The final method is as follows:

```
$link = $this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'ajax', array('ajax'=>true), true);
```

Comment: If you have jQuery, why not use it for the event handling too?

Comment: In the browser dev tool, check the Network tab. Do you see any requests that match the request you're trying to make? If not, check your browser dev tool console for any errors. Update your question with any error messages you're getting.

Comment: Remove "literal" tag and, using Bugzilla or similar, check that ajax url is right.

Comment: @mplungjan How would you propose doing this then? The point of using the php here is the send an email. Since I am working with prestashop I have to use their specific stuff, like functions and methods.

Comment: I mean `const $targetDiv = $("#verifCode");
      $("#showVerifCode").on("click", function () {
        ...
          success: function(data) {
            $targetDiv.show();
            }....`

Comment: @JM-AGMS neither the Network Tab or console are detecting anything when I press the button which is weird.

Comment: @FranCerezo I cant remove the "literal" tag as this is part of the structure of the file and has to be used in this case.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console when you first load the page? It could be that the HTML is not ready yet when JavaScript creates an event listener. If that's the case, then you may need to wrap your code in a [onload event listener](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: @mplungjan I have tried a very similar code to yours that I came up with before your answer, the result was the same. I have added it to the main post.

Comment: @JM-AGMS I dont think this is the case since I just tested some JQuery code without the ajax (so that when the button is pressed it only shows the div) and it works. It only stops working when I add the code. I have edited the main post with some more info about it.

Comment: You can remove it. If not, you must close before {$link->getModuleLink ---} and open again after.

Comment: @FranCerezo This seems to work as I can see the request on the network tab on firefox's tools, but it returns a 404 not found which is weird since the link looks all right. Ill edit the main post again

Comment: Have a look here https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/#ajax-request

Comment: @Crezzur This fixed my problem! I had to add array('ajax'=>true) to the method that gets the link.

Comment: Your welcome ;-)